# Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade hangs at libhin1

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I am on a binge upgrade of servers from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. Some of the upgrades are going fine and some of the servers the upgrade hangs [at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN8RZ.png):

```
Preparing to unpack .../libnih1_1.0.3-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnih1:amd64 (1.0.3-6ubuntu2) over (1.0.3-4.3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnih1:amd64 (1.0.3-6ubuntu2) ...
```

This is a known pitfall and the work around is [found here](https://wildwolf.name/pitfalls-when-upgrading-ubuntu-xenial-to-bionic/).

I am interested in knowing is why is this happening?

PS: These are all systems which are just been upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04 and are almost close to bare Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this help: [How to Upgrade Ubuntu 16.10/17.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 From Command Line](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-16-10-17-04-to-ubuntu-18-04)?